# Python: Error in my code and i don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, string

The example below is failing `upper_lower('abcXYZ')`, it returns true

```
def upper_lower(s: str) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if there is at least one alphabetic character
    in s and the alphabetic characters in s are either all uppercase or all
    lowercase.
    >>> upper_lower('abc')
    True
    >>> upper_lower('abcXYZ')
    False
    >>> upper_lower('XYZ')
    True
    """
    for char in s:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char.isupper() or char.islower():
                return True
            if char.swapcase():
                return False
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: You always return on the first character, so you're not meeting the requirement *"all uppercase or all lowercase"*.

Comment: First you check if the character is a letter with `isalpha()`, then you check if it's either upper or lower, which a latter will always be one or the other. I'm not sure the purpose of that second check.. You might look into checking `all()` or `any()`

Comment: Is this some kind of a home work assignment? Please be transparent about this so we can help without doing your home work. See [Ask] for more on this. Anyway, if you're starting with programming, it helps to manually go through your code with an example. Take the string s = "Rebecca" and go through your code line by line, visualising the status. So 1. `for char in s` -> `char` = "R" 2. `if char.isupper() or char.islower():` -> True 3. `return True` -> function stops and returns "True".

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
def upper_lower(s):
    return s.isupper() or s.islower()

print(upper_lower("abc"))  # True
print(upper_lower("12abc45"))  # True
print(upper_lower("ABC"))  # True
print(upper_lower("ABC45"))  # True
print(upper_lower("aBC"))  # False
print(upper_lower("123"))  # False
```

Your code currently returns True if the first alpha character is eiher lowcase or upcase:

```
if char.isupper() or char.islower():
    return True   # return cause the function to end, other cars are not tested
```

Comment: Works also as a check that at least one character is alphabetic

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using list comprehension for this:

```
def upper_lower(word):
    if not word:
        return False
    else: 
        return all([s.isupper() for s in word]) or all([s.islower() for s in word])
```

Comment: That will return True with an empty string

Comment: And i'd argue an empty string is lower case, correct me :> (joking aside, it's a valid point).

Comment: Also, that could be simplified like this: `return all(...) or all(...)`, no need for the `if else`

Comment: The function should return True "if and only if there is at least one alphabetic character in s"

Comment: fine ... i "fixed" it.

Comment: I can see that :)

Answer (score -1):

```
def upper_lower(s):
    s = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
    return bool(s) and (s.isupper() or s.islower())
```

Comment: to the downvoter: fixed the function calls. it works

Comment: same holds for `isalpha()` so you might as well return `s.isalpha() and (s.isupper() or s.islower())`

Comment: oops, I concur now :)

Comment: i did the same thing originally haha